# How to manage and monitor Spring application

Tags: spring-restcontroller

I have an application, which is designed using spring rest controller and front end it is developed through angular.To integrate this we have used restful web services. To deploy this application Apache tomcat server was used. What is the better way to monitor my application?

Comment: Depends on what you want to monitor